# What is secondary peak to peak of 290BEX transformer if primary pp is 325V and turns ratio 1:2.95?

Tags: amplifier, transformer, simulation, spice, tube

I want to be absolutely sure of this because it is the first crucial part of my LTSpice Fender 5e3 simulation. Currently I have this .subckt(with comments):

```
.SUBCKT HAMMOND_290BEX 1 2 3 4 5 6
*LTSpice allows use of color names to reflect actual code colors 
*of a winding from a transformer specification. 
*Just start the wire name with capital L
*Connect center tap to ground 
*to get 2 opposite phase output voltages for tube rectifier.
*Primary is connected to mains.Black is ground.No floating.
*For example 235Vrms i.e 332V peak in Finland. 
*LTSpice understands peak values as sine voltage source.
*KALL command creates all transformer interactions for each winding. 
*Turns ratio must be converted to inductance values i.e. squared.

*Primary wht_blk is between pins 1 and 2 
*and has reference inductance of 1 and 11.94 ohm dc resistance.
L_wht_blk   1   2           1   Rser=11.94

*red1 to center tap gives noninverted sine peaking at 480V. 
*red BEFORE center tap ->positive start.
L_red1_redyel 3  4      2.175   Rser=61.25

*center tap to blue gives 50Vrms for fixed biasing when needed. 
*blue AFTER center tap -> negative start.
L_redyel_blue 4 5       0.045   Rser=9.28

*inverted sine from other red AFTER center tap
L_redyel_red2   4   6   2.175   Rser=61.25

*Magic happens here:KALL does all guessing automatically 
*for letter capital L started connections
KALL L_wht_blk L_red1_redyel L_redyel_blue L_redyel_red2 1
.ENDS
```

[image: Hammond 290BEX specs]

Lastly what is needed a very simple .asy construct for those 6 pins. Other story.
[image: example of six pin transformer]

Comment: But primary voltage 240VAC is not 325 Vpp, rather 650 Vpp

Comment: Yes. I noticed my error in question. I want to know peak to positive direction and peak to negative direction given 235Vrms which translates to 332.29V positive peak. I want to verify that my .subckt is correct using simulation itself.

Comment: It seems that I got maybe it right because if I connect the ground to other red and center tap unconnected then there is 2kv peak to peak. But if I connect the center tap to ground and both reds to load -100meg- I get two 1kv peak to peak sine voltages. They are in opposite directions like it should be because the next stage is 5Y3 rectifying tube containing two diodes which are dealing with alternating halves.

Answer (score 1):

If the primary is 240VAC and turns ratio is 1:2.95, then the secondary voltage is 708VAC. This  means, the primary voltage is 677Vpp (peak to peak) and the secondary is 2kVpp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMfOSv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So my subckt is wrong. But how would I formulate it so that it would give for example the correct positive side peak assuming 100meg load?

Comment: I think the center tap must be considered too. Because it will be used and the following rectifying tube stage is based on center tap existing making two  identical but 180 out of phase waves for rectifying to work.

Comment: I'm very sorry for asking the question wrong way. Thanks for your time anyway. There should be mention about the need for consider the center tap and that the verifying point would be the positive peak.

Comment: @YoukaNaava The .subckt text file means nothing to me. You could draw an equivalent circuit as I did, then insert data and then you can translate it to subckt

Comment: Well I'm working on LTSpice. I have no energy to learn other software right now. Been on this 11 hours now and learned a lot. But if you understand ltspice schematic I can start working on one which isolates the procedure.

Comment: @YoukaNaava What other software? LTSpice is a simulation of electrical circuit. If you can't draw the circuit on the paper, then you can't draw it in LTSpice, also.

Comment: I would not change Aston Martin for walking stick. We don't need draw circuit necessary because the circuit is in the picture of specification. There you see the center tap and windings. My question is about getting right peak value from .subckt. I know I asked the question totally wrong and apologize but I guess it is clear by now what I'm after. Center tap must be considered because the next stage is a rectifier tube. Somebody with fluency in LTSpice is welcomed to help set up proper transformer subcircuit from Hammond specifications goal being generic tube amp PT code for LTSpice.